# Largest puzzle solvable in one second, assuming it takes f(n) microseconds?

Tags: performance, math, time, execution-time

I have this question:

```
f(n) = log(n) (it's log base 2 btw)
```

What is the largest size n of a problem that can be solved in one second, assuming the problem takes f(n) microseconds?

Well since f(n) is log(n), the problem takes log(n) microseconds, right? And there are a million microseconds in a second, right? So I set it up like this:

```
log(n) = 1000000
```

But that gives 2^1000000 as an answer, and that's an absolutely obnoxiously huge number. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's surely a Big Oh missing in that equation.

Answer (score 3):

That's fine. O(log(n)) algorithms are extremely fast.

Of course in real life f(n) won't be log(n) forever, if you're working on some data-set, you'll  run out of memory and start to hit disk which is going to be slow, and some point later you'll run out of all the disk space on earth...

Comment: Strictly speaking you can't "say O(log(n)) algorithms are extremely fast".  O() is about what happens *in the limit* not necessarily about any real world values of n. Profiling is normally the only way to find out how fast the *implementation* of an algorithm is.

Answer (score 3):

Your math is correct.

An algorithm that runs in log(n) time is one that can cut the size of the problem in half each time. An example would be finding an item in a binary search tree. The worst case would be if the item you are looking for is located in one of the leaves.

So each time you pick a child, you cut off half the tree. At the start you have 2^1 000 000 nodes. When you go down to the next child you have half as many nodes, 2^999 999. After 1 million operations you should be at the leaf that contains the node you were looking for.

Comment: To put it another way, if you can cut the solution space in half *a million times*, then it's a pretty damned big solution space.

Comment: To think about it another way... if you fold a piece of paper in half 42 times, it will be tall enough to reach the moon... Each fold doubles the size of the paper, so if you could fold a piece of paper in half a million times it would be larger than comprehension.

Comment: To put it yet another way, if you cut the observable universe in half about 614 times, you get down to a cubic Planck-length, ostensibly the smallest volume that has any meaning.